# Toastify is not rendered properly

Tags: reactjs

I've created a login page for practicing my skill. The problem is that I am unable to render a toast notification after triggering the handleSubmit function. The flow is that when a "user" submits his or her login information, the toast notification will pop up showing login successfully.

For example, in my code

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

//once the user is verified, toast notification is launched.
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios
        .post("/login", {
          email,
          password
        })
        .then((res) => {
          // this part does not work
          // the notification is not rendered
          toast.success("login successfully", {
            draggable: false,
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT
          });
          setUser({
            ...user,
            err: "",
            success: res.data.message
          });
        });
    } catch (err) {
      err.response.data.message &&
        setUser({
          ...user,
          err: err.response.data.message,
          success: ""
        });
      toast.error(err.response.data.message);
    }
  };
```

Does anyone know is it invoking right? Which approach should I use ??

Here is the sandbox link showing my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-ritchie-1k7p7?file=/src/component/LoginPage.js

Need some help to fix this. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have not included container for a toast to show-up

Need to include this in return function, as shown

```
return (
    <div className="sign-container">
      <div className="sign-wrapper" id="sign-wrapper">
        <ToastContainer/> // Container for toast message


        //rest code


);
```